# Why command runs in terminal but not in extension calls?

Tags: node.js, git, github, vscode-extensions, child-process

If in a terminal I run `git flow release publish '1.0.0'` it is executed successfully.

If I use `child_process.spawn` in a `test.js` and then run it with `node ./test.js` file it also works fine.

But when I use `child_process.spawn` inside VS Code extension it produces error

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
```

If I edit `.git/config` and add my name `https//$myname@github.com......` then error is

```
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://github.com': No such device or address.
```

Here is my code same in test file and VS Code

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

let cmd = 'git';
let args = ['flow', 'release', 'publish', '0.2.8'];
// let args = ['flow', 'release', 'delete', '-f', '-r', '0.2.8'];
const child = spawn(cmd, args);

let stdout = [];
let stderr = [];

child.stdout?.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`[gitflow] Stdout ${data}`);
    stdout.push(data.toString());
});
child.stderr?.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`[gitflow] Stderr ${data}`);
    stderr.push(data.toString());
});
child.on('error', err => {
    console.log(`[gitflow] Error "${cmd} ${args?.join(" ")}" returned`, err);
});
child.on('spawm', err => {
    console.log(`[gitflow] Spawn "${cmd} ${args?.join(" ")}" returned`, err);
});
child.on('exit', code => {
    console.log(`[gitflow] Exit "${cmd} ${args?.join(" ")} exited`, code);
});
child.on('close', retc => {
    console.log(`[gitflow] Command "${cmd}"`, retc, stderr, stdout);
});
```

Comment: Do you have something that could start a credentials manager or set up your environment properly in a terminal (e.g : some code you added to your `.bashrc`), and not when VSCode starts ?

Comment: Thank you, nice direction. I changed the repository link to SSH and set up SSH key authentication. It works. I'll write a memo on Extension readme requirements for extension to function.  But I still want it to work over HTTPS. How I can authenticate user? Which commands to run? I can popup user to enter name and password. Looks like I do not have anything in `.basjrc` or `.profile`.

Comment: You can compare the environment values between your shell and what your vscode script sees, and choose a way to set up the missing values, either when launching VSCode (e.g : create a shortcut which runs `VAR1=VAL VAR2=VAL code` or `source env.sh; code`), or set missing values in your script (`env.VAR1 = "VAL"`, depends on how you can set env vars from your javascript program)

Comment: In general, things using https like to read passwords from the user, so they open `/dev/tty` on Unix-like systems. This works great when there *is* a user and `/dev/tty` grabs hold of that user. It fails utterly when there isn't a `/dev/tty` (the open returns ENXIO, "no such device or address"). Git can be told "don't try" and there are some credential managers that can be used here, but ssh is the way to go.